# NumericMatrix in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

[image]I am writing a code in Rstudio which uses NumericVector and NumericMatrix in Rcpp.
I don't have any problem with NumericVectors but when I want to construct or call a NumericMatrix I get warnings (as the below example).
My code is working correctly but since I don't understand the reason for the warnings, I'm worried it may cause some problems later without me realizing them.
I appreciate if someone help me understand what these warnings means and what I'm doing wrong.

```
//[[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int sim( const NumericVector v1,
     const NumericMatrix m1)
{
  double a = v1[1];     // no warning
  double b = m1(1,1);   // no matching for call to object of type 'const NumericVector' (aka 'const Matrix<14>')
  NumericMatrix c;
  c = NumericMatrix(10,20);    //no matching constructor for initialization of 'NumericMatrix' (aka 'const Matrix<14>')

  std::cout<<"a= "<<a<<", b= "<<b<<", c(1,1)= "<<c(1,1)<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

To run this code, source sim.cpp, define v1 and v2 and then call sim.

```
library(Rcpp)
v1 <- c(1,2,3)
m1 <- matrix(c(11,22,33,44,55,66),nrow = 2)
sourceCpp("sim.cpp")
sim(v1,m1)
```

and you will see

```
[1]a= 2, b= 44, c(1,1)= 0
```

which is the correct answer but I have the warnings anyway.

Comment: This isn't reproducible. What is `it2`?  Why isn't `c` defined? e.g. `NumericMatrix c = ...`.

Comment: @coatless sorry, I updated the sample code to be reproducible.

Comment: Please do not post screen shots.

Comment: While I do not typically edit C++ code in RStudio, when I do it is not uncommon to see warnings *in the code editor* (like the picture you posted) that seem nonsensical and give me no problems when compiling, testing, or using code. I think this is an RStudio issue rather than an Rcpp or C++ issue.

Comment: @duckmayr I think you're right. After seeing comments from other people, it seems like I am the only one who is seeing these warnings so it has something to do with my Rstudio. I tried with another machine and there is no warning. I'm currently trying to understand what is wrong with my Rstudio. It not an old version and has the required packages.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this.  I see

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> sourceCpp("~/tmp/so52632570.cpp")

R> v1 <- c(1,2,3)

R> m1 <- matrix(c(11,22,33,44,55,66),nrow = 2)

R> sim(v1,m1)
a= 2, b= 44, c(1,1)= 0
[1] 0
R>
```

with this cleaned-up smaller version of your code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int sim( const NumericVector v1, const NumericMatrix m1) {
  double a = v1[1];   
  double b = m1(1,1); 
  NumericMatrix c = NumericMatrix(10,20); 
  std::cout<<"a= "<<a<<", b= "<<b<<", c(1,1)= "<<c(1,1)<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}

/*** R
v1 <- c(1,2,3)
m1 <- matrix(c(11,22,33,44,55,66),nrow = 2)
sim(v1,m1)
*/
```

If you want help with an error or warning it helps to have [minimally complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

This question still fails that test.

Comment: You are right. I should have been more clear about my problem.
I see the warnings inside my code script (inline warnings). There is a red sign before the lines that produces the warning. 
After I run the code I get the correct answer without the warning.
I'm not sure how serious these inline warnings are since the answer is correct and they don't show up later in consule.

Comment: I am using the Rcpp quick reference that you have provided.
http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-quickref.pdf
It is using ( ) (e.g. xx(0,1) = 4;) to access an element of a NumericMatrix.
I'm wondering why the code gives correct answer but there are some inline warnings? Would these cause problem?
What am I doing differently for NumericVector and NumericMatrix that causes warning for only one of them?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing read-access (as your `m1(1,1)`) with write-access (`x(0,1) = 4;`). I can't tell because I still reproduce but I don't really want to tell you that a third time.  Please try to make your question more meaningful.